# react router dom v6 doesnt redirect to not found

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

so I just migrated from `react-router-dom` v5 to v6.

As I understand, `exact` doesn't exist anymore because it is omitted. But in my case it doesn't work.

If the route isn't found, it should redirect to `not-found` page, but can't figure out why it is not working. It just prints me a white page...

So, this is my BrowerRouter :

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<AboutUs />} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path="/publish-article" element={<WriteArticle />} />
      <Route path="/search-article" element={<Search />} />
      <Route path="/article/:id" element={<Article />} />
      <Route path="/quizz" element={<Quizz />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
      <Route path="/profile/:username" element={<UserProfile />} />
      <Route path="/profile-settings" element={<ProfileSettings />} />
      <Route path="/not-found" element={<NotFound />} />
      <Route element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Does anybody know what did I miss ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You still need a path for your not found Route and just have it as a wildcard.

```js
<Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
```

But if you are actually wanting the url to redirect to `not-found` then just have the `Navigate` component in there

```js
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'

<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="not-found"/>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to replace last 2 route with this one:

```js
<Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
```

this means if browser not find any path than it will redirect to "*" this path