# How to show error page if route is not available?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have following implementation of React routing. How can I create **Error page** if path not found from **routes** list ?,

```
function App() {
     return (
        <div className="app-container">
            <Switch>
                {routes.map(({ key, path, crumbs, renderComponent }) => {
                    return (
                        <Route key={key} path={path}>
                            {renderComponent(crumbs)}
                        </Route>
                    )
                })}
                <Redirect to="/add-user" />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react router dom v6 doesnt redirect to not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524739/react-router-dom-v6-doesnt-redirect-to-not-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming its V5, It would be something as below...

**Show a 404 Not found**

```
<Route path="*">
  <FourZeroFour />
</Route>
```

**Redirect if not found**

```
<Route path="*">
   <Redirect to="/" />  // replace your home page path
</Route>
```

[If you care, a good blog post on same ...](https://ui.dev/react-router-v5-handling-404-pages)

Comment: It's similar in >v6, but slightly different syntax: 

 `<Route path="*" element={<FourZeroFour />} />`

Comment: yep, seems he uses switch so assuming it's not V6 

Comment: How to redirect to home page if page is not found ?

Comment: you can redirect as mentioned above ....

Comment: FYI rendering `<Redirect from="*" to="/" />` is effectively the same thing and more succinct.

Answer (score 2):

I think, we should to check the availability of key param. If key param was not exist, let's redirect user to Custom element 404 Page not found.

```js
function App() {
     return (
        <div className="app-container">
            <Switch>
                {routes.map(({ key, path, crumbs, renderComponent }) => {
                    return (
                        if(key){
                            <Route key={key} path={path}>
                              {renderComponent(crumbs)}
                            </Route>
                        }
                         else{
                            <CustomElement404PageNotFound />
                        }
                    )
                })}
                <Redirect to="/add-user" />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thank you

Comment: In every scenario, we will get a key in every scenario. we are returning route from map, hence CustomeElement404PageNotFount will not render.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with put Route with path "*" append to last one.